# Erro NullPointerException ao executar while

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public List<Produto> read(){
    Connection con = ConexaoMysql.conectar();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Produto");
        stmt.executeQuery();
        Produto produto = new Produto();

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Entrou");
            produto.setIdProduto(rs.getInt("idProduto"));
            produto.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            produto.setQuantidade(rs.getInt("quantidade"));
            produto.setPreco(rs.getFloat("preco"));
            produto.setSecao(rs.getString("secao"));

            produtos.add(produto);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }finally{
        ConexaoMysql.desconectar(con, stmt, rs);

    }

    return produtos;
```

Esse é o erro que aparece:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at br.com.mercado.dao.ProdutoDao.read(ProdutoDao.java:72)
>     at br.com.marcado.telas.CadastroProduto.readTable(CadastroProduto.java:37)
>     at br.com.marcado.telas.CadastroProduto.<init>(CadastroProduto.java:28)
>     at br.com.marcado.telas.Principal.jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(Principal.java:153)
>     at br.com.marcado.telas.Principal.access$100(Principal.java:15)
>     at br.com.marcado.telas.Principal$2.actionPerformed(Principal.java:81)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Comment: Qual o problema? Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes.

Comment: Como poço fazer para que o while(rs.next( )). Entre para conseguir capturar dos dados no banco.

Comment: Onde é a linha 72 da classe `ProdutoDao.java`?

Comment: While(rs.next( )){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A exceção ocorre porque a variável `rs` está nula, ou seja, você não atribuiu um `ResultSet` para ela.

Também há um erro de lógica no seu código, você não está adicionando um novo objeto `Produto` a cada iteração do `while`, e sim sobrescrevendo e adicionando sempre o mesmo.

Fiz algumas alterações no método, corrigindo o problema do nullpointer e o erro de lógica:

```
public List<Produto> read(){
    Connection con = ConexaoMysql.conectar();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Produto");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            Produto produto = new Produto();
            System.out.println("Entrou");
            produto.setIdProduto(rs.getInt("idProduto"));
            produto.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            produto.setQuantidade(rs.getInt("quantidade"));
            produto.setPreco(rs.getFloat("preco"));
            produto.setSecao(rs.getString("secao"));

            produtos.add(produto);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }finally{
        ConexaoMysql.desconectar(con, stmt, rs);

    }

    return produtos;
```

Comment: Amigo você me salvou agoooora. Deu certissimo.

Comment: @JeanThielisBragaFelipe para servir de referencia para outros usuarios, você pode marcar a respostas como aceita, clicando no `v` ao lado dela :)

Comment: amigo me perdoe mas não to conseguindo localizar esse v

Comment: Tem mas alguma coisa que  eu poça fazer por você ter me ajudado ?

Comment: @JeanThielisBragaFelipe tranquilo agora, se precisar, tamos ai :D